# Proper binding configuration for web service with plaintext password

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, soapui

I am trying to make a web service client in .NET. I added service reference and Visual Studio created the following binding:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="sample" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

but I am getting `q0:FailedAuthentication.`

I found that I am getting results in SoapUI only when I set `WSS_TYPE` to `PasswordText`.

How can I set the binding configuration in .NET/WCF to get the same request?

Below is SoapUI request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:rnl="sample" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" 
                   xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
                   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3">
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">XXXX</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>date</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <rnl:GetLastUpdate/>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ClearUsernameBinding](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html) in case there is no SSL. If there is SSL use this:

```
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NewBinding0">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

and in either case turn on wcf log and trace on the server to see how your message differs from soapUI and what are the inner server exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer with help of:
http://benpowell.org/supporting-the-ws-i-basic-profile-password-digest-in-a-wcf-client-proxy/

I needed to add a header in BeforeSendRequest

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
        {
            UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken(this.Username, this.Password, PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
            XmlElement securityToken = token.GetXml(new XmlDocument());
            MessageHeader securityHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", securityToken, false);
            request.Headers.Add(securityHeader);
            return null;
        }
```